# Iterating over generators with while

Tags: php, pdo, php-generators

I'm writing a PDO wrapper for a new project. A very common pattern with SQL is to write a statement such as

```
while ($row = $connection->fetch($sql)) {
    ...
}
```

My wrapper function is essentially this:

```
public function fetch($query, $bindings)
{
    $stmt = $this->getPdo()->prepare($query);

    $stmt->execute($bindings);

    $stmt->setFetchMode($this->getFetchMode());

    foreach ($stmt as $record) {
        yield $record;
    }
}
```

But I can't use the values if I call this using a `while` loop as above. Doing a `var_dump` says that `$row` is a Generator object. If I use a `foreach`, a `var_dump` shows the database data, as expected. Is it simply not possible to traverse over generators using `while`, or have I confused myself here somewhere?

Comment: That is because a generator is not a traversable object. Think of it like that: a traversable object needs some known amount of elements you can iterate over. That is not the case for the result set of a query. The object does _not_ know how many entries it contains, since it does not hold all those entries. For good reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it simply not possible to traverse over generators using while, or have I confused myself here somewhere?

You have confused yourself ;) In your code sample:

```
while ($row = $connection->fetch($sql)) {
```

You actually execute `fetch()` for every iteration of the loop. With generators you typically use `foreach()`:

```
foreach ($connection->fetch($sql) as $row) {
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and I couldn't get enough distance to see it at the time